# Getting error while trying to build Android application using Delphi 12

Tags: java, android, delphi, pascal

I have installed Delphi 12.0 and tried to build Android 64 bit application and I'm getting error that Can not execute the Java.exe. Currently, I'm using Jdk1.8 and do I need to use any specific version of Java for Delphi 12?

Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9wtV.png)

I have tried to revert the Libraries but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Delphi 12 requires the Adoptium JDK, which you can install using Tools | Manage Features. You should ensure that the JAVA_HOME environment variable points to this JDK

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, I update java (and java SDK)
[image: Installed Java]
After those updates, D12 found the necessary Java.exe

Comment: I have re added the configuration manually for Android. Now, the problem does not occurs. Thanks